# I would like to uninstal windows vista and just use ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

hi I am new to ubuntu after could anyone help me to remove windows I don't want this option when I log in to my laptop, please answer without to much technical jargon if possible

Answer (score 3):

There are a few tools that can do it quite easily and in graphic mode. You can check [OSUninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) for Ubuntu.

Please note that everytime you mess with GRUB/The OS installed on your system, you should back up your personnal data.

Comment: That looks like a nice util! :)

Comment: @Jo-Erlend Schinstad It simplifies the task a lot :) It is easier than the alternative where you have to erase manually your windows partition & reconfigure GRUB

Comment: Does it also resize the other partitions and filesystems?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The freed partition should be unallocated. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows#Use_the_Newly_Freed_Space) for more info on how to configure it nicely.

Comment: Hi there just want to say a big thank you for helping me sort out this problem

Comment: No problem :) If this answer was useful, please vote up and accept it, so that it closes your question